# !AIRLINE CODE NOT FOUND on SABRE ACS_CheckInPassengerRQ

Tags: sabre

i'm trying to consume this service

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/sabre_sonic_apis/soap/check_in/check_in_passenger

and the server responds with the message "!AIRLINE CODE NOT FOUND"

Does anyone know anything about this?

(request here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d3ccda8326dda50497e1ecca39cf6939)

Thanks!

Comment: Check-in services are intended for airlines only. Are you developing for an airline?

Comment: yes bruno it's correct, im developing for an airline

Answer (score 1):

Are you connecting to the AA sabre partition?  Also the flight you are trying to check into doesn't depart until 2018, so that request will fail anyway with a "FLIGHT NOT INITIALIZED" error after you get past this particular error.